# Why does rounding the floating-point number 1.4999999999999999 produce 2?

Tags: python, floating-point, language-agnostic, rounding

I've been reading a book [Write Great code - Understanding the Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593270038). In the section about rounding it says:

> Numbers should be rounded to the smallest bigger number if the decimal bit value is more than or equal half the total decimal value that can be represented.

which means:

```
round(1.5) // equals 2
round(1.49) // equals 1
```

but when I tried this with Python:

```
x1 = 1.4999  # rounds to 1

x2 = 1.4999999999999999  # rounds to 2

print(round(x1))

print(round(x2))
```

the output was:

> 1
>
> 2

I tried the same thing with C# and Swift and it gave the same output. So I assume it's a language-agnostic topic.

But why does this happen?

My assumption is that the **floating-point unit** rounds the extra bits which convert the "1.4999999999999999999" to "1.5" before applying the programmer's rounding.

Comment: Sorry, wrong jump there. `1.4999999999999999999` is not a number that float can represent separate from `1.5`. Floats are an approximation to real numbers.

Comment: It can't be represented exactly in binary, and the closest floating point representation happens to be `1.5` exactly. `1.4999999999999999 == 1.5` is `True`. If you trim off a `9` you'll see the behavior you expect: a number slightly less than 1.5 is indeed rounded down.

Comment: Assuming IEEE 754 64-bit binary, the error on rounding the real number 1.4999999999999999999 up to 1.5 is 1E-19. The error on rounding it down to the next smaller exactly representable number, 1.4999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375, is 2.219446049250313080847263336181640625E-16. It is a simple case of round-to-nearest on conversion to floating point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `x2 = 1.4999999999999999` and `print(round(x2))`, there are two operations that affect the value. The `round` function cannot operate directly on the number 1.4999999999999999 or the numeral “1.4999999999999999”. Its operand must be in the floating-point format that the Python implementation uses.

So, first, 1.4999999999999999 is converted to the floating-point format. Python is not strict about which floating-point format a Python implementation uses, but the IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary format is common. In this format, the closest representable values to 1.4999999999999999 are 1.5 and 1.4999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375. The former is closer to 1.4999999999999999 than the latter is, so the former is used.

Thus, converting 1.4999999999999999 to the floating-point format produces 1.5. Then `round(1.5)` produces 2.